# External HDD unrecognized

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

I have an external IDE harddrive. I plug the USB to the PC, switch on the power and I hear that the HDD is working(no scratch, no shar noise, just a smooth hdd is what I hear). My problem is, that the PC can't recognize the external HDD. The Windows waiting circle shows me that the PC try to install the USB components, but after about 10-20 minutes later it stops. When it try to install the USB components, the HDD name is like random characters, like this: N%:4ljks:&{{}-4USB . Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: Do you have another computer to connect this to?  Is it a desktop external hard drive (with a separate power supply) or a laptop external hard drive (that draws power via the USB and might require a dual head cable)?  Do you have the ability to remove the drive from the external drive casing and connect it directly to the computer?  Are you connecting it to a laptop or a desktop?  Do the USB ports in the computer work normally otherwise?

Comment: I've tried it on a desktop and a laptop, and it's a desktop external hard drive, with a separate power. I can disassamble the external hard drive so I've put it into my PC and it worked. But a few minutes later my PC had frozen. From that moment the external hard drive doesn't work properly.

Comment: Might be a power issue, but almost definitely sounds like a dead/dying/defective drive.

Comment: Is there any way to save data from it?

Comment: There may be.  There is a host of software out there that can copy data from drives that can still be accessed, there are data recovery companies out there that can use a few different methods to attempt to recover your data... it really depends on how much you want to spend.

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question to multiple sites. This is abusive behavior.

Comment: Bon Gart: Thank you for your answers!
Daniel Beck: Sorry, first I tried on SO because I didn't know this site. They said on SO to try here too.